# python/Django syntax error in Exception handling

Tags: python, django

In the code below i m getting syatax error in Error handling statements'
i m using ATOM text editor. django for web interface and netmiko libaray for my backend code.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from first_app.forms import CmdForm
from django.http import HttpResponse
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from netmiko.ssh_exception import NetMikoTimeoutException
from paramiko.ssh_exception import SSHException
from netmiko.ssh_exception import AuthenticationException
import datetime, time, sys
   # Create your views here.

def index(request):
    my_dict = {'insert_me': ""}
    return render(request,'first_app/index.html',context=my_dict)

def form_name_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CmdForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            from netmiko import ConnectHandler
            ipInsert = request.POST.get('ip_address', '')
            devices = {
            'device_type':'cisco_ios',
            'ip':ipInsert,
            'username':'mee',
            'password':'12345',
            'secret':'12345',
            }
            cmd = request.POST.get('command', '')
            try:
                netconnect = ConnectHandler(**devices)
            except(AuthenticationException):
                print ('Authentication failed' + ipInsert)
            continue           #position 1
                continue       #posiiton 2
            getIP = netconnect.send_command(ipInsert)
            output = netconnect.send_command(cmd)
            now = time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M%S")
            file = sys.stdout
            file = open("C:/Users/karti/OneDrive/Desktop/frontend/ "+now +".txt", mode='w+')
            file.write("IP address is\n"+ ipInsert)
            file.write("\n\nCommand Executed: \n"+ cmd)
            file.write("\n\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
            file.write("\n\nOutput of Executed Command: \n\n\n"+output)
            file.close

            return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {'form': form, 'output':output, 'getIP':getIP, 'date_time':now})
        else:
            form = CmdForm()
        return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {})
```

Error when continue at position 1

> from first_app import views
>     File "K:\Work\DevNet\first_project\first_app\views.py", line 33
>       continue
>       ^
>   SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop

Error when continue at position 2

> File "K:\Work\DevNet\first_project\first_app\views.py", line 33
>       continue
>       ^
>   SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop

Comment: #some code here#  Please provide complete code.

Comment: And there should be `except:` block after `try`

Comment: Learn  about python indentation,  https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation

Comment: when adding except i get the error at continue

Comment: Don't change the topic of your question in reaction to the already given answers!

Comment: `continue` without a loop doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Matthias As in, i have to use for/while loop, in order to get the continue working ?

Comment: No, as in why have you used `continue` at all? What do you think it does?

Comment: there are multiple except statements.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

codes below are true:

```
cmd = request.POST.get('command', '')
try:
    netconnect = ConnectHandler(**devices)
except Exception as e:
    print ('Authentication failed' + ipInsert)
    continue
getIP = netconnect.send_command(ipInsert)
```

Comment: tried your given code but i m getting the error          Exception(AuthenticationException):
                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Nope.! didnt worked. its reporting the error   ::::---- SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop

Comment: use pass Instead continue

Comment: But why `pass`? Just use no statement at all.

Answer (score 0):

- In python due to incorrect alignment, there might be errors, in your program, `try` and `Exception` do not seem to be aligned.
- There should be an `except` block for each try, where you would catch the exceptions thrown from `try` block.
- Also, there seems to be error at 31st line, but posted code is less