# Passing the error message on web page using django

Tags: python, html, django

how can i pass the Error exception messages onto the webpage. I m using Atom text editor and django

views.py

```
try:
    netconnect = ConnectHandler(**devices)
except (AuthenticationException):
    re = print ('Authentication failed ' + ipInsert)
    return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {'form': form, 'reprinting':re})
```

forms.html

```
{% if request.POST %}
<pre>{{ reprinting }}</pre>
{% endif %}
```

its priting *None* rather then printing the error message in code.

NOTE:-although the described error message is printing on command line in text editor

for full code refer the link :
[full code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57034006/python-django-syntax-error-in-exception-handling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        try:
            netconnect = ConnectHandler(**devices)
        except (AuthenticationException):
            re = ('Authentication failed ' + str(ipInsert))
            return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {'form': form, 'reprinting':re})
```

this should do it

Answer (score 2):

The [**`print(..)`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function does *not* return content. It prints the value to the standard output channel, and returns `None`.

If you want `re` to contain the error message, you need to assign it, like:

```
try:
    netconnect = ConnectHandler(**devices)
except AuthenticationException:
    re = 'Authentication failed {}'.format(ipInsert)
    print(re)
    return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {'form': form, 'reprinting':re})
```

Note that you should check with:

```
{% if request.method == 'POST' %}
{% endif %}
```

since a POST request can be empty, but then it is still a POST request.